# Do the following positive series converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

$(d_k)$ is a positive sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ with:
$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n d_k = \infty.$

Do the following series converge or not?

a) $\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{d_n}{1+d_n}$
b) $\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{ d_n}{1 + n d_n}$,
c) $\sum_{n\geq1} \frac{d_n}{1 + n^2 d_n}$
d) $\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{d_n}{1+d_n^2}$

Comment: You can certainly eliminate some of them by considering a constant sequence, e.g. $d_n = 1$ for all $n$.